# Not getting a response from the flask route to ReactJS frontend

Tags: json, reactjs, flask

I am passing form data from ReactJS frontend to flask backend for a prediction problem and expect to get the prediction in JSON format but I am unable to receive any response from the backend.

React frontend code:

```
handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.patientData)
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        result: response.result
      })
    })
}
```

Flask backend code:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def handleJSON():
    data = request.get_json(force = True)
    test_data = list(data.values())
    test_data = pd.DataFrame([test_data])

    # Column Transformer   
    ct_pkl = open('ct.pkl', 'rb')
    ct = pickle.load(ct_pkl)
    test_data = ct.transform(test_data)

    # Logistic Regression Model
    lr_pkl = open('lr.pkl', 'rb')
    model = pickle.load(lr_pkl)
    pred = model.predict(test_data)

    response = jsonify({"statusCode": 200, 'result': pred[0]})
    return response
```

Comment: What is being collected in your response variable?

Comment: It should hold the JSON object (passed by Flask) but I am not getting anything back (there isn't a network request for that JSON object in the network tab)